# How can I make XML act like Android XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, xslt, intellij-idea

I understand how to write XML for Android. I would like to somehow define, for lack of the correct term, class for XML, so that I can create instances of it and require certain attributes or elements. A few hours of Googling didn't help, so I am here as a last resort. Here's a little more detail of what I'd like to do.

```
<CLASS-TEMPLATE>
 <required_element required_attribute=""></required_element>
 <required_element required_attribute=""></required_element>
</CLASS-TEMPLATE>

<Class-Instance id="0" name="name">
     <required_element required_attribute="0">Something</required_element>
     <required_element required_attribute="1">Something else</required_element>
</Class-instance>
```

I would like the Intellij compiler to inform me that I am missing attributes or elements like it does for Android, but I have no idea how to. I experimented with `xsl:templates` but I am lost.

TL;DR How can I make regular XML act like Android xml, so I can define required attributes and elements for a class I define and instantiate?

Comment: The word you are looking for is "schema". A schema describes a class of XML documents. You will find lots of information (on StackOverflow and elsewhere) by searching for "schema for Android XML".

Comment: Here's an [introduction to XML Schema](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-xml-schema/). However, there is no default [schema for Android XML](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/2FtsLQ4wESY), so you will have to roll your own. I'm afraid you will have to sieve through the TL;DR this time...

Comment: @MichaelKay yes, that is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @Abel thanks for the link!